# How to copy the selected and processed text to clipboard?

Tags: javascript, clipboard

I am making a chrome extension in which I am performing the following tasks.:-

1)copying the selected text in browser

2)removing all spaces and special characters from text and changing any uppercase text to lowercase

3)copying the final processed task to clipboard

I am successfully able to complete first two tasks:

```js
var text=window.getSelection().toString().replace(/[^A-za-z0-9]/g,'');
text=text.replace(/\s+/g,'').toLowerCase();
window.prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C or cmd + C(mac), Enter", text);
```

for the third task I am prompting user to copy himself,but I want the copy to be done directly to clipboard without prompting the user. Is this possible?For IE I found a code snippet for copy to clipboard but I want this to be working in chrome. The document.execCommand('copy') only copies the current selection and not the processed text as far as I am aware. Any suggestions are welcome.

**Note**: For those not aware: Since this is browser based ,you have to run the js on browser console to see the results of this. In chrome press ctrl+shift+j to open console. Select some text from a webpage .Copy paste this code and see the results

Comment: Create hidden input, put processed value, do copy command

Comment: hi @Justinas Can you elaborate or give some reference

Comment: if you mean input type = hidden , that will not fulfill my requirement as I want the copy from anywhere on any site ,irrespective of which tag it is residing

Comment: IE 10+, Chrome 43+, Firefox 41+, and Opera 29+ support these commands.

Safari does not support these commands.

Comment: @JaydeepPandya good to know that.But my main focus is chrome really,so doesnt matter much